# Servant: see all request headers

Tags: haskell, http-headers, servant

I know from the documentation that I can do something like the following to capture a specific header:

```
type MyApi = "view-my-referer" :> Header "from" Referer :> Get '[JSON] Referer
```

But I'm exploring some webhooks that aren't well documented, and I'd like to just inspect *all* the headers in the request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use [Network.Wai.Middleware.RequestLogger](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/wai-extra-3.0.24.3/docs/Network-Wai-Middleware-RequestLogger.html#v:mkRequestLogger) to log headers for all incoming requests, regardless of which Servant endpoint ends up handling the request.  I've used this to understand under-documented APIs, and for other sorts of debugging.